# Can dead scorpions still sting?

Tags: arachnology

I found a dead scorpion on the sidewalk today, and brought it home, being careful not to touch its stinger. Bees can sting even after they are dead, if you step on them in such a way that it pushes their stinger out.

**Does the same apply to scorpions?**  Do I need to be careful not to touch its stinger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the bark scorpion can still sting after death. I learned this myself after stepping on one. As I make a nightly habit of patrolling inside my home for their presence, I can conclude the offender had died within 12 hours of my stepping on it. When they die their tails stretch straight behind their bodies, this was the position I found it in.